# MVC Routing removing query string.

Tags: model-view-controller, routes

/Routeurl?value=1

Gets redirected to...

/Routeurl/

Where as...

/RouteUrl/?value=1

stays as...

/RouteUrl/?value1

I need the query string parameters in there. How do I get routing to ignore them!

EDIT

This only happens on IIS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routing should ignore them inherently if the Routes are not defined in the Global.asax file.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default",
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }
);
```